# discord.js - not sending messsage

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to do an command for my discord bot but when I try to use it the bot do not show response.
normally the bot had to response : "`resultat pour => def: ${defenseValue}, hp: ${hpValue} égal: ${resultat}`". but nothing happen.
I think the error are at the starts of the code but I don't know why.

here the code :

```
    
    module.exports = {
    name : 'eHP',
    async run (client,message){
       if(message.content.startsWith("!eHP")) {
        // sépare le message en tableau pour chaque espace vide trouvé
        // exemple: "!eHP def 55 hp 42" <=> ["!eHP", "def", "55", "hp", "42"]
        const parts = message.content.trim().split(' ');
         
        // récupére la valeur de defense
        let defenseValue = parts[2];
         
        // récupére la valeur HP
        let hpValue = parts[4];
         
        // convertit les valeurs en nombre
        defenseValue = parseFloat(defenseValue);
        hpValue = parseFloat(hpValue);
         
        if(isNaN(defenseValue) || isNaN(hpValue)) {
            // une valeur n'a pas put être convertit en nombre
            // abandon du calcul
            if(isNaN(defenseValue)) {
                // ces la valeur de defense qui na pas put être convertit
                message.reply(`defense valeur doit être nombre, reçu: "${parts[2]}"`);
            } else {
                // ces la valeur de hp qui na pas put être convertit
                message.reply(`hp valeur doit être nombre, reçu: "${parts[4]}"`);
            }
        }
         
        // les valeurs on été recupéré depuis le message
        // elles on été convertit en nombre il faut appliqué le calcul
         const resultat = (((defenseValue * 3.5 ) + 1140) * hpValue) / 1000;
          
         // le calcul à été effectué il faut renvoyé un message avec le résultat
         message.reply(`resultat pour => def: ${defenseValue}, hp: ${hpValue} égal: ${resultat}`);
    }
    }
    // le bot à reçu une commande
    // il le reconnait car le message commence par: !eHP

    }
```

and my main files look like that :

```
 
    const Discord = require('discord.js'),
    client = new Discord.Client(
    {
      fetchAllMembers: true
        
    }),
    config = require('./config.json'),
    fs = require('fs')

    client.login(config.token)
    client.commands = new Discord.Collection()

    fs.readdir('./commands', (err,files) =>{
        if (err) throw err
        files.forEach(file=> {
            if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return
            const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
            client.commands.set(command.name, command)
        })
    })

    client.on('message',message => {
        if(message.type !== 'DEFAULT' || message.author.bot) return
        
        const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g)
        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase()
        
        if (!commandName.startsWith(config.prefix)) return
        const command = client.commands.get(commandName.slice(config.prefix.length))

        if (!command) return
        command.run(message, args, client)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions looks correct.
In your main file, you need to import this file

```
// assuming you have a folder with all commands and the file name of your code is eHP.js
const ehpCommand = require('./commands/eHP.js')
```

A command handling system could maybe look like this

```
// add your commands
const commands = [
  ehpCommand,
];

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('message', msg => {
  let command = commands.find(e => e.name === msg.content.split(' ')[0]);
  if(command){
    command.run(client, msg);
  }
})
client.login(<your_token>);
```

---

**After answer edit:**

One thing i see here, you are using a Discord.Collection you set the commands with

```
bot.commands.set(...)
```

which is correct and probably a better approach than the one i provided, but now you can't use

```
commands.find(...)
```

since you don't have an array where commands are stored, you can access elements of a collection this way

```
command = messsage.content.split(' ')[0];
if(!client.commands.has(command) return;

client.commands.get(command).run(client,msg);
```

---

Another thing i saw in your code, your run method expects 2 parameters (client, message), but you pass 3 parameter into the function (message, args, client), you should keep an eye on the order and amount of parameters you pass to the function.

Since the order of your arguments is not correct, it would also make sense, why you don't get a response

Comment: i edit my answer for add my main files, the code it's not good ? when i look what you told me to do, it's exactly what i wrote.

Comment: @victor I have edited my answer corresponding to your change, hope it solves your problem